# How to make operations on the value of a concurrent map atomic?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, concurrenthashmap

Let's say I have the following field inside of a class:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<SomeClass, Set<SomeOtherClass>> myMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<SomeClass, Set<SomeOtherClass>>();
```

An instance of this class is shared among many threads.

If I want to add or remove an element from a set associated with a key, I could do:

```
Set<SomeOtherClass> setVal = myMap.get(someKeyValue);
setVal.add(new SomeOtherClass());
```

The `get` operation is atomic, therefore thread-safe. However, there's no guarantee that, in between the `get` and the `add` instruction, some other thread won't modify the structure messing with the first one's execution.

What would be the best way to make the whole operation atomic?

Here's what I've come up with, but I don't believe it to be very efficient (or to be making the best use out of Java's structures):

I have a ReentrantLock field, so my class looks like this:

```
class A {
    ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    ConcurrentHashMap<SomeClass, Set<SomeOtherClass>> myMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<SomeClass, Set<SomeOtherClass>>();
}
```

Then the method call looks something like this:

```
lock.lock();
Set<SomeOtherClass> setVal = myMap.get(someKeyValue);
synchronized(setVal) {
    lock.unlock();
    setVal.add(new SomeOtherClass());
}
```

The idea being that we let go of the lock once we have made sure no one else will access the Set we're trying to modify. However, I don't think this is making the best use of the `ConcurrentMap` or that it makes much sense to have a lock, a concurrent structure, and a `synchronized` block all used to achieve one operation.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Since Java 7, you don't need to repeat the generics in the constructor, you can simply your hash map construction to `new ConcurrentHashMap<>()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ConcurrentHashMap` guarantees that the entire method invocation of `compute` (or `computeIfAbsent` or `computeIfPresent`) is done atomically. So, e.g., you could do something like this:

```java
myMap.compute(someKeyValue, (k, v) -> {v.add(new SomeOtherClass()); return v;});
```

**Note:**
Using `compute` is analogous to the original snippet that assumes that `somKeyValue` is present in the map. Using `computeIfPresent` is probably safer, though.